# Computing Hermite Normal Form using Extended Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to calculate the Hermite Normal Form of a square $n \times n$ matrix using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to compute the columns of the HNF matrix, rather than the standard (column) matrix operations.  According to Cohen [[Coh93]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387556400), this is possible using the following algorithm, where $a_{i,j}$ denotes the coefficients of a matrix $A$, $A_{j}$ denotes column $j$ of the matrix $A$, and $B$ is an auxiliary column vector.

$
\def\indent{\qquad}
  k \leftarrow n\\
  j \leftarrow n\\
  \text{for } i \leftarrow n \text{ to } 1 \text{ do}\\
    \text{    compute } (u, v, d) \text{ such that } ua_{i,k} + va_{i,j} = d = \gcd(a_{i,k},a_{i,j}) \text{ with } |u| \text{ and } |v| \text{ minimal (see below)}\\
    \text{    while } j \geq 1 \text{ do}\\
    \indent\text{    if } a_{i,j} \neq 0 \text{ then}\\
    \indent\indent B \leftarrow uA_{k} + vA_{j}\\
    \indent\indent A_{j} \leftarrow (a_{i,k}/d)A_{j} - (a_{i,j}/d)A_{k}\\
    \indent\indent A_{k} \leftarrow B\\
    \indent\text{    end if}\\
    \indent\text{    } j \leftarrow j - 1\\
    \text{    end while}\\
  \text{end for}\\
  \vspace{5mm}\\
  \text{// Final Reductions}\\
  k \leftarrow n\\
  \text{for } i \leftarrow n \text{ to } 1 \text{ do}\\
    \text{    } b \leftarrow a_{i,k}\\
    \text{    if } b < 0 \text{ then}\\
      \indent\text{    } A_{k} \leftarrow -A_{k}\\
      \indent\text{    } b \leftarrow -b\\
    \text{    end if}\\
    \text{    if } b = 0 \text{ then}\\
      \indent\text{    continue}\\
    \text{    end if}\\
    \text{    for } j \leftarrow k+1 \text{ to } n \text{ do}\\
      \indent\text{    } q \leftarrow \lfloor a_{i,j} / b \rfloor\\
      \indent\text{    } A_{j} \leftarrow A_{j} - qA_{k}\\
    \text{    end for}\\
    \text{    } k \leftarrow k - 1\\
  \text{end for}\\
$

Note that the Euclidean step requires that $|u|$ and $|v|$ be minimal.  This means that of all the possible unique pairs, $(u,v)$ be chosen such that

$
  -\frac{|a|}{d} < v \text{sign}(b) \leq 0 \text{ and } 1 \leq u \text{sign}(a) \leq \frac{|b|}{d}
$

My algorithm for calculating the minimum $|u|$ and $|v|$ therefore consists of the following:

$
  d, u, v = \text{XGCD}(a_{i,k},a_{i,j}); \text{// Using XGCD defined by Magma} \\
  x_{0} \leftarrow u \\
  y_{0} \leftarrow v \\
  \text{if } (u = 0) \text{ or } (v = 0) then \\
    \text{    for } i \leftarrow 0 \text{ to } d \text{ do} \\
      \indent\text{    } u \leftarrow x_{0} - i \times b / d \\
      \indent\text{    } v \leftarrow y_{0} + i \times a / d \\
      \indent\text{    if } -\frac{|a|}{d} < v \leq 0 \text{ and } 1 \leq u \leq \frac{|b|}{d} \text{ then} \\
        \indent\indent\text{    break} \\
      \indent\text{    end if} \\
    \text{    end for} \\
  \text{end if} \\
  \text{return } d, u, v \\
$

Here, I have assumed that Magma's XGCD returns the correct sign for $u$ and $v$.

To test this algorithm, I am using the following sample matrix as input to the procedure:

$
  \left(
    \begin{array}{rrrr}
      10 &  0 &  1 &  0 \\
      -2 & -2 &  2 &  1 \\
      -2 & -1 &  3 & -1 \\
       4 & -6 & -2 &  0 \\
    \end{array}
  \right)
$

I expect the following output from the procedure:

$
  \left(
    \begin{array}{rrrr}
      33 & 12 & 12 & 11 \\
       0 &  6 &  5 &  1 \\
       0 &  0 &  1 &  0 \\
       0 &  0 &  0 &  2 \\
    \end{array}
  \right)
$

Instead, I am getting the following output:

$
  \left(
    \begin{array}{rrrr}
      3168 & 48 & 48 & 47 \\
         0 & 24 & 22 & 18 \\
         0 &  0 &  2 &  1 \\
         0 &  0 &  0 &  2 \\
    \end{array}
  \right)
$

It is apparent that there is no problem with the steps that reduce the lower triangular part of the matrix, nor with the steps that reduce the upper triangular part of the matrix (that is, the Final Reduction steps).  The problem therefore lies with the Euclidean step.

My question is whether or not I have correctly implemented the procedure that returns the minimal values for $|u|$ and $|v|$?  Note that I have used the following link relating to Linear Diophantine Equations as a guideline to implementing this procedure: [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Euclid.27s_lemma_and_unique_factorization). Is this correct, or should I be tackling this problem a different way?  Either way, where could I find a better reference that better describes the problem at hand?  Any help/advice would be appreciated.

References:

[[Coh93]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387556400) H. Cohen, *A Course in Computational Number Theory*, Vol. 138 of *Graduate Texts in Mathematics*. Springer, Heidelberg, 1993.

Comment: Are the `\indent` and `\vspace` commands working for you?! I just see the command sequences in red instead (Firefox 10.0.2 and Safari 5.1.2).

Comment: Unfortunately, the `\indent` and `\vspace` commands are not working for me either.  I am also seeing them in red.  I figured it's the best that I can do under the LaTeX style mathematics mode.  Note that I have a running version of this algorithm written in Magma.  I refrained from copying and pasting it with this question since I do not want the group to think that I am asking them to debug the program for me.

Comment: I hope you won't find me too presumptuous for putting `\def\indent{\qquad}` in the top of the first math mode block. I hope this is acceptable and works for everyone.

Comment: @bgins - Yes, it works for me!  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are some errors, either book errata, or transcription errors, in the stated algorithm. Firstly, $k$ is the pivot column, so it needs to be decremented (whenever nonzero) at the end of the first $i$ loop. Secondly, for *each* iteration in this loop, $j$ needs to be looped over from $k-1$ down to $1$, to clear out the lower triangular part, so it must be initialized inside the $i$ loop.

I am also skeptical of whether special handling of xgcd is necessary or even helpful, since it always returns a "positive definite" $d$ (an admitted abuse of terminology), in the sense that it is (or should be) always positive given $(a,b)\ne(0,0)$. Because of this, we also do not need the $b < 0$ test (and correction) in the final (partial upper triangular) reductions. In fact, it seems rather artificial to require $v \le 0$ and $u > 0$ of xgcd. What about $(a,b)=(3,1)$ and $(-1,3)$? Also, your pseudocode for the xgcd wrapper only alters its output if $u$ or $v$ is zero, and I think the loop could be avoided by solving some linear equations (taking quotients and a minimum).

However, I don't have Cohen's book, and don't know how or why he requires $|u|$ and $|v|$ to be minimal. Does he mean that $\max\{|u|,|v|\}$ must be minimal? I admit, I haven't thought deeply about it. But I think it is a fact that xgcd already does a good job of producing a minimal solution.

I have corrected the algorithm, as I think it should be, and implemented it in [sage](http://www.sagemath.org). After testing described below, I also made a correction.

```
m = Matrix(ZZ,4,4,\
    [[10,-2,-2, 4]\
    ,[ 0,-2,-1,-6]\
    ,[ 1, 2, 3,-2]\
    ,[ 0, 1,-1, 0]]).transpose(); m

def hnf(m,show=False):
    nr = m.nrows()
    nc = m.ncols()
    if show:
        print 'hnf: '+str(nr)+'x'+str(nc)
    assert(nr == nc)
    c = m.columns()
    M = Matrix(ZZ,nc,nr,c).transpose()
    if show:
        print M
    def r(n):
        s = range(n)
        s.reverse()
        return s
    k = nc - 1
    pivots = []
    for i in r(nr):
        for j in r(k):
            ck = c[k]; a = ck[i]
            cj = c[j]; b = cj[i]
            if b != 0:
                d,u,v = xgcd(a,b)
                if show:
                    print 'row '+str(i+1)+', cols '+str(j+1)+','+str(k+1)\
                        , 'xgcd:',u,'(',a,') + ',v,'(',b, ') = ',d
                ad = a/d
                bd = b/d
                c[k] = ck*u  + cj*v  # if a != d:
                c[j] = cj*ad - ck*bd
                M = Matrix(ZZ,nc,nr,c).transpose()
                if show:
                    print M
        if c[k][i] != 0:
            pivots.append((i,k))
            if c[k][i] < 0:  # this is necessary for the last pivot column,
                c[k] = -c[k] # since it cannot utilize xgcd to "normalize"
            k = k - 1
    for (i,k) in pivots:
        b = c[k][i]; assert(b > 0)
        if show:
            print 'pivot('+str(i+1)+','+str(k+1)+')='+str(b)
        for j in [k+1..nc-1]:
            q = floor(c[j][i] / b)
            c[j] -= c[k]*q
        M = Matrix(ZZ,nc,nr,c).transpose()
        if show:
            print M
    pivots.reverse()
    #if show:
    #    print 'pivots:', pivots
    return M, pivots

h,p = hnf(m,True)
```

Here is the output (for your test case):

```
hnf: 4x4
[10  0  1  0]
[-2 -2  2  1]
[-2 -1  3 -1]
[ 4 -6 -2  0]
row 4, cols 3,4 xgcd: 0 ( 0 ) +  -1 ( -2 ) =  2
[10  0  0 -1]
[-2 -2  1 -2]
[-2 -1 -1 -3]
[ 4 -6  0  2]
row 4, cols 2,4 xgcd: 1 ( 2 ) +  0 ( -6 ) =  2
[ 10  -3   0  -1]
[ -2  -8   1  -2]
[ -2 -10  -1  -3]
[  4   0   0   2]
row 4, cols 1,4 xgcd: 1 ( 2 ) +  0 ( 4 ) =  2
[ 12  -3   0  -1]
[  2  -8   1  -2]
[  4 -10  -1  -3]
[  0   0   0   2]
row 3, cols 2,3 xgcd: -1 ( -1 ) +  0 ( -10 ) =  1
[12  3  0 -1]
[ 2 18 -1 -2]
[ 4  0  1 -3]
[ 0  0  0  2]
row 3, cols 1,3 xgcd: 1 ( 1 ) +  0 ( 4 ) =  1
[12  3  0 -1]
[ 6 18 -1 -2]
[ 0  0  1 -3]
[ 0  0  0  2]
row 2, cols 1,2 xgcd: 0 ( 18 ) +  1 ( 6 ) =  6
[33 12  0 -1]
[ 0  6 -1 -2]
[ 0  0  1 -3]
[ 0  0  0  2]
pivot(4,4)=2
[33 12  0 -1]
[ 0  6 -1 -2]
[ 0  0  1 -3]
[ 0  0  0  2]
pivot(3,3)=1
[33 12  0 -1]
[ 0  6 -1 -5]
[ 0  0  1  0]
[ 0  0  0  2]
pivot(2,2)=6
[33 12 12 11]
[ 0  6  5  1]
[ 0  0  1  0]
[ 0  0  0  2]
pivot(1,1)=33
[33 12 12 11]
[ 0  6  5  1]
[ 0  0  1  0]
[ 0  0  0  2]
```

Sage also has a hermite_form function for matrices,

```
var('s')
for s in ['pari', 'pari0', 'pari4', 'padic', 'default', 'ntl']:
    print str(s)
    print m.hermite_form(algorithm=s)
```

but each implementation produces the matrix below
$$
\left(\matrix{
 2 & 0 & 2 & 27 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 64 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 45 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 66
}\right)
$$
which, as you point out in a comment, is arrived at by iterating over $i$ *increasing*, i.e. by pivoting from the top (left) downwards,
rather than *decreasing* from the bottom (right) upwards.
We can verify this directly using the transformation
$\phi:m\mapsto rm^tr=(rmr)^t$, for $r$ the (orthogonal) matrix
$$
r=
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),
$$
which transposes $m$ by *both* diagonals. Our (Cohen's) HNF (which pivots from the bottom right upward) and sage's (which forms pivots from the top left downwards) can be obtained from each other by pre- and post- transforming by $\phi:$

```
r = Matrix(ZZ,4,4,[\
    floor(1/(1+n%3))*\
 (1-floor(1/(1+n%15)))\
    for n in range(16)])
print r
phi = lambda x: (r*x*r).transpose()
print phi(m).hermite_form() == phi(h)
phi(phi(m).hermite_form())
```

By the way, if you don't mind a little excursion, the group of transformations of square matrices generated under composition by the (self-inverse) maps $\color{red}{t}:m\mapsto m^t$ (transpose) and $\color{blue}{r}:m\mapsto rm$ (row reversal) or $\color{green}{c}:m\mapsto mr$ (column reversal) is in fact isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of the square. We can visualize this group by its action on a fixed matrix, e.g. the $2\times2$ matrix $e=\left(\matrix{1&2\\3&4}\right)$.
[image: The dihedral group of a square as vertices of a cube]

Each transformation is represented by, or identified with, (a path from $e$ to) a vertex. The order two elements consist of the surface edges and interior diagonals, while the rotations consist of the face diagonals, and their cosets partition the vertices into two intersecting tetrahedra. This is also a commutative diagram, and thus can be used to verify such formulas as $rc=cr$, $rt=tc$, and $ct=tr$ as well as $\phi=rtc=trc$ from above.

Anyway after some testing

```
ranks = [0,0,0,0,0]
passed = 0
failed = 0
for n in range(10^2):
    m = random_matrix(ZZ,4)
    h, p = hnf(phi(m))
    if phi(h) == m.hermite_form():
        ranks[len(p)] += 1
        passed += 1
    else:
        print 'Test FAIL!'
        print 'm:'; print m
        print 'm"=phi(m):'; print phi(m)
        print 'hnf(m"):'; print h
        print 'hnf(m")":'; print phi(h)
        print 'm.hnf():'; print m.hermite_form()
        failed += 1
        break
print n+1,'tests performed:',passed,'passed,',failed,'failed.'
print 'rank counts:',ranks
```

I found that I needed to sometimes correct the sign of the first pivot column, and incorporated this into the `hnf` function above (along with making the print output optional but off by default). In any case, in sage, you can just define $\phi$ and use `phi(phi(m).hermite_form())`; after all, why should we add a seventh implementation (except to learn!)?

Comment: Thanks for that!  I also suspected that the minimal condition isn't necessary since, like you mentioned, XGCD does a good job of returning the minimal solution anyway!  Note that the algorithm that I have provided is an *interpretation* of that provided by Cohen, and is therefore likely to contain errors.  I have, however, discovered and compensated for errors in this and other algorithms provided.  Also, thank you for providing the Sage source code and, especially its output. It will give me a guideline to correcting the source code which I have written in Magma.

Comment: Discovered the problem!  At the step where I was reducing the lower triangular portion of the matrix, I was forgetting to divide the coefficients by the GCD of both a and b.  I would have NOT realised this if I had not looked at your coding example, which divides the coefficients by the GCD on separate lines.  You are also right about XGCD returning the *minimal* values.  As for the implementation of HNF provided by Sage, you'll find that it commences from the top-left corner of the matrix, rather than the bottom right corner of the matrix described by Cohen's algorithm.

Comment: If you transpose the matrix on the diagonal commencing from bottom left to top right, and take the HNF of the resulting matrix under Sage, you'll find that this produces the same results as this algorithm (but, you probably knew that).  Once again, thank you for your help!  Really appreciated.

Comment: Transposing on that diagonal is a similarity transformation by the permutation (and therefore orthogonal) matrix $r$ which reverses columns (rows) upon right (left) multiplication: `r = Matrix(ZZ,4,4,[1 if n%3==0 and n%15!=0 else 0 for n in range(16)]); print latex(r); r` $$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$ To get our matrix, we have to perform a pair of transpositions, the regular one, and the conjugate by $r$ (which commute with each other): `r*(r*m.transpose()*r).hermite_form().transpose()*r` Thanks for the fun Q!

Comment: Thank you for your support!

Comment: My pleasure! I also discovered an error after some testing: the first pivot column could have a negative pivot value, since it couldn't benefit from xgcd to normalize itself. Please see the improved post for the new code.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  Probably more than I needed to know, but invaluable nevertheless.  I've actually moved on to implement the next HNF Algorithm in Cohen's text that reduces the calculations modulo the determinant of the matrix.  This method was contributed by Hafner and McCurley.  While the methods of reduction remain pretty much the same, it handles the pivot in a slightly different way.  If you're up to the challenge, I can email you the Magma code of what I have done thus far.  I can also email you my solution to this exercise.

Comment: Unfortunately, my version of Sage is a bit outdated: it's using version 2.6 of Python, whereas I've upgraded to version 2.7.  While I have no problems writing code, I do have a problem loading the sample solution that you posted.  As this is not a priority at the moment, upgrading Sage is on my list of things to do.

Comment: If you're on Linux (and not using one of those VM's), just type `sage -upgrade` from the command line an hour before you go to bed and then make sure you hit the confirmations (I don't think there were many). If you want, you can back up all your worksheets at once, first, and make sure you remember your password and that all your worksheets are stopped so their pickle files don't get corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll give it a try later today.  Note that I am running my software on a MacBook Pro with the latest OS X 10.7.3 Lion.

Comment: Just to let you know that I have posted a similar question concerning the computation of HNF using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm modulo the determinant of the matrix.  Unlike the other two algorithms that I have successfully implemented, this does not specifically cater for the zero case, nor does it specifically reduce the lower triangular portion of the matrix.

Comment: As for the Sage upgrade, I did not do this as there are issues with the upgrade under the latest version of Mac OS X 10.7.3.  I did manage, however, to upload the worksheet using Sage's notebook().  Not sure why it didn't allow me to do this on the command line.  Either way, all works well.